# Nested collapsible elements: initialize a collapsible inside of content for another collapsible

Tags: accordion, collapsible

Having a

```
data-mage-init='{
"collapsible":{
    "collapsible": true,
    "openedState": "opened",
    "multipleCollapsible": true,
    "header": ".parent__collapsed",
    "content": ".parent__expanded"

}}'>
```

inside of the `parent__expanded` I need to initialize another collapsible element saying

```
data-mage-init='{
"collapsible":{
    "collapsible": true,
    "header": ".child__collapsed",
    "content": ".child__expanded"

}}'>
```

However, nothing happens on the child, while moving it out of the parent's content perfectly works.